# What does the 'sort' attribute do?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

Following is the snippet from the hibernate mapping file, of the class named `m1`.

```
<class name="pojo.m1" table="m1">

  <id name="r_no">
      <generator class="increment" />
  </id>

  <property name="s_name" />

  <map name="map" table="m4" cascade="all" sort="pojo.m4">
      <key column="r_no" />
      <index-many-to-many class="pojo.m2" column="t1" /> <!-- r_no as index !-->
      <many-to-many class="pojo.m3" column="t2" /> <!-- r_no + total OR class m3 as key !-->
  </map>

</class>
```

In the `map` tag, there is an attribute named `sort`. What does it do ? Here it names the class that implements the `comparator` class.

```
public class m4 implements Comparator<m2> {

    @Override
    public int compare(m2 o1, m2 o2) {
        if(o1.getR_no() > o2.getR_no()) 
            return 1;
        else 
            return -1;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-mapping):

```
sort (optional): specifies a sorted collection with natural sort order or a given comparator class.
```

It specifies that your mapped collection is sorted and by what criteria it is sorted. In your case a comparator is given that defines the order of two objects and therefore iterativly the order of all objects.

Comment: and what if I remove the `sort` attribute ?

Comment: I think the default will be unsorted.

Comment: See also section 6.3.1 in the documentation.

Comment: and when is the `compare` method called ? Because I see no relevance of this attribute..Even if I remove it, I get the same result

Comment: I don't know exactly. Have you tried debugging it? Also I'm guessing that the elements in your database are already ordered so you get an ordered result even without the `sort` attribute.

Comment: I don't know.Can you please have a look at the code here.`m1,m2,m3,m4` are all pojo classes.while `runner` is the one that commits.There is also a mapping xml file.https://github.com/suhailgupta03/hibernate.git